# How can I round down a float?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I need to somehow round down float values with a precision of two decimal points, for futhur computation.

For example if I have 0.1098 I need it to become 0.10 and if i have 0.1176 I need that to become 0.11.

Pretty much I guess I need to truncate my floats to 2 decimal points

Answer (score 14, accepted):

usually you do rounding when converting it to a string, since binary floats can't always exactly represent 2 decimal digits. To get an NSString with 2 digits, use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", num];
```

If you *really* want to truncate to a float for further computation, use something like

```
((int)(num * 100)) / 100.0
```

and if you want to round instead of truncate

```
((int)(num * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0
```

Comment: Damn, so quick on the answer!  This is btw the correct answer.

Comment: except he wants to round down not up, so don't add .5

Comment: well i need to pass that float value to a function (it's the time interval for an NSTimer) so would I just convert that back to a double by calling [myString doubleValue] ?

Comment: nevermind I just noticed the other part of your answer, thanks